SUPER slow charging (UBUNTU 24.04 LTS)
I have a problem with charging in ubuntu. 3 days ago, when i close my laptop, it charge speed as normal as usual, but when i turn on again, do some task without plugin battery charge, it down at 90% and when i plugin charge, and check time consuming to fully charge, it take 230 hours. Even when i shutdown and wait for 1 day, battery just 91%. Im sure that my battery at good condition. Please help me!
About my computer
 Kernel: 6.8.0-48-generic 
 OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64 
 CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7 (8) @ 4.700GHz  
 GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
 GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX330 

and when i use
  upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0

It show like this
battery
present:             yes
rechargeable:        yes
state:               charging
warning-level:       none
energy:              24.7608 Wh
energy-empty:        0 Wh
energy-full:         27.474 Wh
energy-full-design:  41.9976 Wh
energy-rate:         0.0114 W
voltage:             12.743 V
charge-cycles:       N/A
time to full:        9.9 days
percentage:          90%
capacity:            65.418%
technology:          lithium-polymer
icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'

